# intel compiler on vista: "unable to obtained mapped memory"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, memory, compiler-construction, intel

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile C++ projects using intel compiler version 10.0.025 on vista business edition (sp1) in vs2008:

```
unable to obtain mapped memory (see pch_diag.txt)
```

There is no such file as pch_diag, so that's a bit disheartening.

If I try to just use the microsoft compiler, all of my calls to intel's integrated performance primitives (ipp) are met with an access error into the program files directory where the ipp is stored.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer:

Run icl in xp sp2 compatibility mode.  It won't work in vista mode. Which is a bit odd, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running the compiler as a standard user (good for you!), and the errors you get with the Microsoft compiler seem to point towards a permissions problem. You should use Windows Explorer to check the security properties for the directory you mentioned, if you haven't already. If the problem isn't apparent from the security properties page, here are some tools that may be useful for debugging permissions problems:

- [LUA Buglight](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2006/08/07/LuaBuglight.aspx): a tool for finding the causes of "LUA" (Limited User Access) bugs
- [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx): a tool for monitoring filesystem and registry access in real-time. You can filter out all processes other than the compiler, then look for "ACCESS DENIED" errors.

Comment: can this happen when I'm administrator?